# Normal map baking (cycles): some parts missing, other parts exist a second time at wrong spot

Tags: uv, texture-baking, normal-map

I have a scene with two models: A door and a doorframe. For each there's a low- and a high-polygon mesh. While baking the high details from the high-poly door to the low-poly door works just as expected, i get strange results for the doorframe: Some parts missing, other parts exist a second time at the wrong spot. More details further down.

But first, how i did it:

- I'm using the cycles renderer.
- Created a low-polygon and a high-polygon model and ensured that they are positioned at the exact same spot.
- Unwrapped the low-polygon model.
- Created an empty texture for the low-polygon model in the UV view.
- Created a new material in the node editor and added a "image texture" node, and added the empty texture to that image texture node.
- In the bake menu of the render menu i set "bake type" to normal, "space" to tangent, "margin" to 16 and checked "selected to active". I tried different ray-dists, the one on the screenshot is 2.000.
- Then i selected the high-poly model, then shift-selected the low-poly model and pressed bake.

Now some more detailled explanations and illustrations:

In the following image you see how the lower part of the high-polygon doorframe model looks: The hinges are slightly more detailled and on the elevation at the left and right there are elevated notches. (Sorry, couldn't post the low poly model image, need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 images, but i think you get it anyways.).

[image: The high-polygon doorframe model]

In the next image you see the faulty normal-map.

1) These are the UVs (from the low poly model) of the hinges. As you can see on the side of these UVs there is some normal coloring going on.

2) ...but strangely there are also normal-colors generated on the frame, where the hinges are actually positioned on the model. But that's not where the UVs of the hinges are on the UV map (see 1).

3) That's where the normal-colors of the notches should be created, but nothing's there. Some rather strange normal-colors will be generated there if i set a check mark in the cage-checkbox of the bake-menu.

[image: The normal map]

Thanks for any hints or workarounds.